# Monero vs Stellar

Tags: cryptocurrency-comparison

I wonder how Monero stands compared to Stellar in terms of privacy and scalability. An in-depth comparison is appreciated and will be awarded with bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Apples to oranges would be an understatement. They are not comparable. Monero is a private, decentralized, secure, untraceable, fungible digital *currency*. Stellar is not.

Comment: Well, you just compared them. But I'm looking for an in-depth one.

Answer (score 0):

Stellar uses bulletproofs, something adopted around the same time as Monero. However, there is no protection for sender and recipient privacy, only the amount sent.

This isn't an issue if two banks are obviously going to be interacting with each other, but it means if a user wishes to be private, that privacy is diminished by the opt-in characteristics of the network, as well as their addresses being easily correlated.